# Text in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want that when the "Start" button is pressed, it executes code and counts from 3 (3... 2... 1... Ready!), with delay between each and printing the numbers in the program window. I used tkinter. But I can't get the countdown to appear when I press the "Start" button. And I don't know how to add the code that is executed after pressing the button.

---

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import time
class Aplicacion:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master=master
        self.master.title('Title')
        self.master.geometry('290x50')
        self.inicializar_gui()
    def inicializar_gui(self):
        lbl_bienvenido=tk.Label(self.master,text='Hi!',font=('Helvetica',10))
        lbl_bienvenido.place(x=0,y=0)
        btn_login=tk.Button(self.master,text='Start')
        btn_login['command']=self.comando
        btn_login.place(x=10,y=23)
    def comando(self):
        entry = ttk.Entry(state=tk.DISABLED, takefocus=False)
        entry.place(x=63, y=25)
        entry.insert(0, "1...")
        # print("3")
        # time.sleep(1)
        # print("2")
        # time.sleep(1)
        # print("1")
        # time.sleep(1)
        # print("Ready!")
def main ():
    root = tk.Tk()
    ventana = Aplicacion(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

Comment: do you want the countdown to appear in the console or in the in your window ?

Comment: In the window .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an exemple that you could adjust to your need :

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
txt = tkinter.Text(root)

a = 4
def countdown():
    global a
    if a>0:
        txt.delete('1.0','end')
        a -=1
        txt.insert('0.0',str(a))
        root.after(1000,countdown)
    if a == 0 :
        txt.delete('1.0','end')
        txt.insert('0.0','Ready!!')

btn = tkinter.Button(root,text = 'START',command = countdown)
txt.pack()
btn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```